# how to add methods to class attributes in python?

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I'm creating a custom class to store information about a CFD simulation results.

Right now the way it is set up is that it instantiates an empty class object, then used a method called `load_mesh` which calls an external function to read all the information about the mesh, and return a dictionary of all the information. The `load_mesh` method then assigns a bunch of class attributes from the values in the dictionary.

The problem is that I am planning to store alot more information than just the mesh, and I dont want to have like 1000 attributes to my class object. I want to store then in appropriate containers(?) that each have their own methods.

For example, my code looks like this currently (some stuff omitted that's unnecessary):

```
class CFD():
    def __init__(self, infile=None):
        self.file = infile

    def load_mesh(self):
        mesh = load_cfd_mesh(self) #calls outside function to load mesh info, uses self.file, returns dict
        self.proj = mesh['proj']
        self.static_items = mesh['static_items']
        self.nnodes = mesh['nnodes']
        self.node_coords = mesh['node_coords']
        self.node_codes = mesh['node_codes']
        self.nelements = mesh['nelements']
        self.element_types = mesh['element_types_str']
        self.node_connectivity = mesh['node_connectivity']
        self.element_node_ids = mesh['element_node_ids']
        self.element_coords = mesh['element_coords']
        self.element_elevs = mesh['element_elevs']
        self.horizontal_units = mesh['horizontal_units']
        self.vertical_units = mesh['vertical_units']

test = CFD('testfile.txt') #instantiate
test.load_mesh() #load mesh information to attributes
```

Now, I can access any of the mesh information by doing:

```
test.proj
self.nnodes
self.coords
```

etc...

But want I want to do is store all of this information in `test.mesh`, where `test.mesh` has all of these attributes but also has the method `test.mesh.load()`.

I THINK I can do something like this:

```
class CFD():
    def __init__(self, infile=None):
        self.file = infile
        self.mesh = None

    def load_mesh(self):
        mesh = load_cfd_mesh(self) #calls outside function to load mesh info, uses self.file, returns dict
        setattr(self.mesh, 'proj', mesh['proj'])
        #etc....
```

then I'd be able to do:

```
test = CFD('testfile.txt') #instantiate
test.load_mesh() #load mesh information to attributes
test.mesh.proj
```

But I can't figure out how to add the `load_mesh` method to `self.mesh`?

How is it possible to achieve the following way of doing this:

```
test = CFD('testfile.txt') #instantiate
test.mesh.load() #load mesh information to attributes
test.mesh.proj
```

Do I have to define another class within the main class? Like `class mesh(self):`

Also, if my proposed way of adding attributes to self.mesh doesn't make sense..please help!

Comment: You want to replace a dict with a class with attrbiutes? Except for a little of readability, I wouldn't recommend this. Stick to use a dict: it's a perfectly fine data structure for this. Don't force it into a class just because `mydata.some_key` seems a tiny bit nicer than `mydata['some_key']`.

Comment: ok regardless of how I store the information in `self.mesh` how can I add the `load` method to it, the main question is adding a method

Comment: @00 No, `class CFD():` is fine, if a little odd looking.

Comment: In the end I can do `self.mesh['proj']`if I want, but how can I load the mesh info by calling `self.mesh.load()`

Comment: @chepner There's actually more going into the class I just deleted it for the sake of minimalism for the question..shouldve deleted the paranthesis, but either way

Comment: Why do you need `x.mesh.load()`? What would `load()` do on an existing object?

Comment: @chepner Can you point me to some reference that shows both uses are fine (and if one is preferred over another)? Now I'm curious, as I'm used to no parentheses.

Comment: @00 The grammar allows it, and the semantics are identical to no parentheses.

Comment: @AKX the goal would be to call `x.mesh.load()` and have it instantiate a bunch of attributes to `x.mesh`, so afterwards I could access the resulting information from the load, like `x.mesh.proj`

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a `Mesh` class that does just that. Possibly with `load` class method.

Comment: @00 like an inner class? define the Mesh class within the CFD class? does that make sense? - I'm a rookie

Comment: No, just a separate class, and instantiate that inside the `CFD` class.

Comment: It could still be messy, depending on whether you want the attributes such as `mesh.proj` to exist at all before `mesh.load()`, or just to have a `None` value initially.

Comment: But, frankly, I think you're over-engineering your data structure.

Comment: @00 the reason I'm taking this approach is because I'm going to be storing mesh info, results info and some other stuff... I just want it to be obvious where mesh info is stored (`x.mesh`) and where other stuff is stored (`x.results`) - I dont want to have like 100 attributes in the main class..and I also want to access them by attributes instead of keys in a dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you  might be looking for something like a property to lazily load the mesh when needed – I don't really see why there'd be an "empty" mesh object you explicitly have to `.load()`:

```
class Mesh:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        mesh = load_cfd_mesh(filename)
        self.proj = mesh["proj"]
        self.static_items = mesh["static_items"]
        # ...


class CFD:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self._mesh = None

    @property
    def mesh(self):
        if not self._mesh:
            self._mesh = Mesh(self.filename)
        return self._mesh


test = CFD("testfile.txt")
print(test.mesh.proj)
```

Comment: I think this might be exactly what I'm looking for - at work but I'll try it out at some point today and get back to you..appreciated

Comment: this is more "how you should do it". you might not want its `__init__`to do the loading, and keep the loading method on `CFD` though - because I think code will look strange - on the very first access you'd have to thread cfd.mesh as a callable, `cfd.mesh("myfile")` and on the subsequent accesses you'd use `cfd.mesh.mesh_attr` . If the loading is triggered on `CFD.__init__` this would be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks to both. This is the route I went. I didn't include the load in the init  because the meshes could potentially be huge and if it's not needed I don't want to waste time initializing the class instance. It will load once if needed then remain loaded for subsequent calls

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with an inner class (below is a simplified code for demonstrating):

```
class CFD:
    class Mesh:
        def __init__(self, file):
            self._file = file

        def load_mesh(self):
            # implement here your own code...
            print("loading from file", self._file)
            self.proj = "PROJ"

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.mesh = self.__class__.Mesh(file)
```

Comment: thanks, between yours and @AKX 's approach, I think I'll be able to achieve what I'm trying to do.. I'll be able to test this later and get back to you..much appreciated

Comment: note that you gain nothing by nesting the class declarations themselves - here  `class Mesh` could be - and probably should - outside the body of `class CFD` itself.  If you look at the hundreds of thousands of projects of web-backend code that use relational databases, where, say, a `Person`  must have an associated instance of `Contact`, that is the way it is done.

Comment: @jsbueno: I gain encapsulation. If the Mesh class is intended to be used outside of the CFD class, then it must be declared outside. If all of its objects are intended to be attributes of CFD objects, then it is better to make it an inner class.

Comment: this is not a usual practice, and I hope you at least akcnowledge that. One can have enough encapsoluation by putting the code in the correct module files.  
It may feel more semantic  - and that may be a good thing.

Ah - I remember the tricky part of doing that - is that one might think that from inside a `Mesh` instance you can get to the owner CFD  - and there are no implicit mechanisms for it. If needed the owner must be passed explictly to Mesh's `__init__`. 

Otherwise than that, the objection comes really just to "flat is better than nested"

Comment: Thanks for your help but I ended up making a external class so accepted the other answer. Much appreciated